# JAX-WS Web Service Client - JDK 17 - simple Java client w/ a main() - Fails

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jax-ws, java-17

I have been digging to understand why a simple Java class w/ a main() method that attempts to instantiate a client proxy client call to a JAX-WS web service running on WildFly v27 keeps failing w/ an exception related to jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider.

- The client app is built using Maven (JAR artifact) based on the
  pom.xml shown
- JDK is Corretto v17 No compile errors are seen.
- JAR is created w/ the expected content which is only a few class files.

Java client to test
WSDL URL works fine
Debugger using "Step Into" reaches into jakarta.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:82) before it all comes apart as shown in the stack trace.

It's clearly a runtime classpath issues, I have applied suggested changes  to the pom.xml (what is shown is the current state) and have not been able to get this to create the simple call to the RUNNING service.  The various changes (from online researching and articles related to similar issues)

I hope I am just missing the obvious and making a mindless error -it's not clear to me why this does not work.

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws.client;

import jakarta.xml.ws.Service;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.net.URL;


public class WSClient {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WSClient.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WSClient wsClient = new WSClient();

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/employee-service/EmployeeService?wsdl");
            QName qName = new QName("http://localhost:8080/employee-service/EmployeeService");

            Service service1 = Service.create(url, qName); // exception occurs on this line

            EmployeeService employeeService = service1.getPort(EmployeeService.class);
            Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(9000);
            System.out.println("Employee:" + employee.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Interface

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws.client;

import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface EmployeeService {

    @WebMethod
    public Employee getEmployee(@WebParam(name = "id", targetNamespace = "http://ws.jaxws.example.com/") int id);
    @WebMethod
    Employee addEmployee(int id, String name);
}
```

POJO class

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws.client;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
@XmlType()
public class Employee {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXWS_Client-NEW</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JAXWS_Client-NEW</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jakarta-xml-ws-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Stack trace at console:

```
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.isOsgi(FactoryFinder.java:214)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:124)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:64)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:735)
    at com.example.jaxws.ws.client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:21)

jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to createEndpointReference Provider
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:68)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:735)
    at com.example.jaxws.ws.client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider (com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl and jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:64)
```